# Tor is set for javascript but getting message I must

Tags: javascript

English

This page cannot function without javascript. Please enable javascript and reload the page.

Yet Javascript is set to TRUE.  I have had this issue in a couple of other browsers in the past.  I think either Brave or Vivaldi.   I am doing a search with Startpage when I get this error.
I don't know what else to try to correct this error.
Duck Duck go onion allows me to go to a non javasite for the search results.  What the hey?  My Tor is definitely being read as not allowing java when it is set to true under the config.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, usual reason for that is that some *particular* script can not be executed, not the JS site-wide disabling... Also a Tor browser is a questionable thing, but it's better than nothing - and it has it's glitches, quite a ton of them. But as you've referenced - that Brave and Vivaldi has had the same issue as well - the reason is in the page's scripts for sure. Try using Developer tools in Brave or Firefox - press F12 for them - and look at the Console tab, reload page if needed. Then you'll see more details about the particular error